# Buffer overflow/overrun explanation?

Tags: c, assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

In the given url this function is given:
http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html

```
void function(int a, int b, int c) {
   char buffer1[5];
   char buffer2[10];
   int *ret;

   ret = buffer1 + 12;
   (*ret) += 8;
}

void main() {
  int x;

  x = 0;
  function(1,2,3);
  x = 1;
  printf("%d\n",x);
}
```

The corresponding assembly code for main function is:

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x8000490 <main>:       pushl  %ebp
0x8000491 <main+1>:     movl   %esp,%ebp
0x8000493 <main+3>:     subl   $0x4,%esp
0x8000496 <main+6>:     movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x800049d <main+13>:    pushl  $0x3
0x800049f <main+15>:    pushl  $0x2
0x80004a1 <main+17>:    pushl  $0x1
0x80004a3 <main+19>:    call   0x8000470 <function>
0x80004a8 <main+24>:    addl   $0xc,%esp
0x80004ab <main+27>:    movl   $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x80004b2 <main+34>:    movl   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
0x80004b5 <main+37>:    pushl  %eax
0x80004b6 <main+38>:    pushl  $0x80004f8
0x80004bb <main+43>:    call   0x8000378 <printf>
0x80004c0 <main+48>:    addl   $0x8,%esp
0x80004c3 <main+51>:    movl   %ebp,%esp
0x80004c5 <main+53>:    popl   %ebp
0x80004c6 <main+54>:    ret
0x80004c7 <main+55>:    nop
```

In the variable `ret`, they are pointing `ret` to the address of the next instruction to be run. I cannot understand that just by keeping the next instruction in the `ret` variable, how is the program going to jump to this next location?
I know how buffer overflow works, but by changing the `ret` variable, how is this doing buffer overflow?
Even by considering that this is a dummy program and is just supposed to let us understand how buffer overflow works, changing the `ret` variable seems wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Explanation of how this is an example of a buffer overrun:**

The local variables of `function`, including `buffer1`, are on the stack, along with the return address, which is calculated as being 12 bytes beyond `buffer1`.  This is an example of a buffer overrun because writing to an address 12 bytes beyond `buffer1` is writing outside the proper bounds of `buffer1`.   By replacing the return address by a number 8 larger than it was, when `function` finishes, rather than popping off a return to the statement following the function call as usual (`x = 1;`, in this case), the return address will be 8 bytes later (at the `printf` statement, in this case).

Skipping the `x = 1;` statement is not the buffer overflow -- it's the effect of the buffer overflow which modified the return address.

**Note on the calculation of 8 as the proper offset for skipping `x = 1;` statement**:

See also [FrankH's careful reevaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19615959/290085) of the calculation of 8 as the proper offset to add to the return address to achieve the intent of skipping `x = 1;`.  His findings contradict the GDB-based analysis of the [insecure.org source article](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html).  *Regardless of this detail, the explanation of how a buffer overrun is used to change the return address remains the same* -- it's just a question of what to write into the overrun.

For completeness, here is the **GDB-based analysis of the [insecure.org source article](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)**:

> What we have done is add 12 to buffer1[]'s address.  This new
>   address is where the return address is stored.  We want to skip pass
>   the assignment to the printf call.  How did we know to add 8 to the
>   return address?  We used a test value first (for example 1), compiled
>   the program, and then started gdb:

```
[aleph1]$ gdb example3
GDB is free software and you are welcome to distribute copies of it
 under certain conditions; type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB; type "show warranty" for details.
GDB 4.15 (i586-unknown-linux), Copyright 1995 Free Software Foundation, Inc...
(no debugging symbols found)...
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x8000490 <main>:       pushl  %ebp
0x8000491 <main+1>:     movl   %esp,%ebp
0x8000493 <main+3>:     subl   $0x4,%esp
0x8000496 <main+6>:     movl   $0x0,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x800049d <main+13>:    pushl  $0x3
0x800049f <main+15>:    pushl  $0x2
0x80004a1 <main+17>:    pushl  $0x1
0x80004a3 <main+19>:    call   0x8000470 <function>
0x80004a8 <main+24>:    addl   $0xc,%esp
0x80004ab <main+27>:    movl   $0x1,0xfffffffc(%ebp)
0x80004b2 <main+34>:    movl   0xfffffffc(%ebp),%eax
0x80004b5 <main+37>:    pushl  %eax
0x80004b6 <main+38>:    pushl  $0x80004f8
0x80004bb <main+43>:    call   0x8000378 <printf>
0x80004c0 <main+48>:    addl   $0x8,%esp
0x80004c3 <main+51>:    movl   %ebp,%esp
0x80004c5 <main+53>:    popl   %ebp
0x80004c6 <main+54>:    ret
0x80004c7 <main+55>:    nop
```

> We can see that when calling function() the RET will be 0x8004a8,
>   and we want to jump past the assignment at 0x80004ab.  The next
>   instruction we want to execute is the at 0x8004b2.  A little math
>   tells us the distance is 8 bytes.

A little better math tells us that the distance is `0x8004a8 - 0x8004b2 = 0xA` or 10 bytes, not 8 bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The layout on the stack is like this (addresses downwards - as stacks grow):

```
buffer + ...       value found       description
=================================================================================
+24                3                 # from main,     pushl $0x3
+20                2                 # from main,     pushl $0x2
+16                1                 # from main,     pushl $0x1
+12                <main+24>         # from main,     call  0x8000470 <function>
+8                 <frameptr main>   # from function, pushl %ebp
+4  %ebp(function) padding (3 bytes) # ABI - compiler will not _pack_ vars
+0                 buffer[5];
...                buffer1[12];      # might be optimized out (unused)
...                int *ret          # might be optimized out (reg used instead)
```

The tricky thing is that `buffer` starts at a four-byte-aligned address even though it's not sized a multiple of four bytes. The "effective size" is eight bytes, so if you add eight bytes to the start of it, you find the saved framepointer, and if you go another four bytes down, the saved return address (which, according to your disassembly, is `main+0x24` / `0x80004a8`. Adding 8 to that jumps "into the middle" of two intructions, the result is garbage - you're *not* skipping the `x = 1` statement.

Comment: Nice catch. Updated my answer to note the mistake you found. +1